# Context does not exist in current context (Android Project)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm fairly new to Xamarin and trying out different tutorials from Xamarin developers' website. I'm testing a notification code for Android and getting "Context does not exist in the current context" error. I place the following code inside MainActivity.cs. How do I fix this issue?

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder (this)
.SetContentTitle ("Sample Notification")
.SetContentText ("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
.SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);

// Build the notification:
Notification notification = builder.Build();

// Get the notification manager:
NotificationManager notificationManager =
GetSystemService (Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

// Publish the notification:
const int notificationId = 0;
notificationManager.Notify (notificationId, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I don't need Context to access NotificationService. I think it's because I'm in the context already.